# undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass - listing for a specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There are posts, comments & users. I want to post number of comments for a specific user in comments list on Post show page. I know I need to define @user, but I don't know how to define it, so that it shows specific number for every user. User is author of the comment.

*Post controller*

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comments = Post.find(params[:id]).comments.order(created_at: :desc)
  @user = ???
end
```

Post /show action - **error is for - @user.comments.count**

```
<div class="row">
<% @comments.each do |comment| %><br>

<div class="col-sm-4"> <%= link_to comment.user.name, user_path(comment.user) %> <br> 
<%= image_tag(comment.user.smallimage) %><%= @user.comments.count %>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8"> <b><%= comment.title %>:</b>   
<div>
<% if comment.content.length > 250 %>
<%= truncate(comment.content, length: 250) %>
<%= link_to_function '...Read more', "$(this).parent().html('#{escape_javascript  comment.content}')" %>
<% else %>
<%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
</div>  
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried @user= User.find(params[:id])

Comment: Yes, but it show that it can't find a user with id=[id_of_post]

Comment: Could you edit the question to include information on **what** a user is? is the user the author of the post? Are they visitors?

Comment: User is the author of the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define an `@user` you will only have one user or a group of users that doesn't relate to your comments. You don't need it. You can just use the relationship between user and comment like this:

```
<%= comment.user.comments.count %>
```

Note that this will run a database query for each comment to get the total comment count for that user. For performance reasons you may want to use a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) for this instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you defined the association in the post model `belongs_to :user` then you can probably do `@user = @comment.user`

But, if that's the case then you can call that from the view with `@comment.user.name` or something like that.

I'd like to see the whole codebase if you've pushed to GitHub.

Comment: Yeah so if you defined the association then you should be able to called comment.user.name from the view without any trouble. Rails magic my friend.

Comment: It is defined User has_many :comments, Comment belongs_to :user. Error is for: @user.comments.count

Comment: Can you post the GitHub repo? If you defined the has_many relationship then the @user.comments.count should work fine. Did you try the first (slightly hacky) solution I mentioned?

Comment: Actually, try @comment.user.comments.count

Comment: It's in my private repo. I tried all of your suggestions, but I get the same error. Do you have any other suggestions for defining @user?

Comment: Since he's doing `@comments.each do |comment|`, it should be `comment.user.comments.count`, not `@comment.user.comments.count`. He's